# Game won't change rotation with iPhone's rotation in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I have a problem that in cocos2d when I run my game it runs in portait mode even though the default orientation is landscape. http://gyazo.com/99bd018dc52c7f3311cb09eb5c7229d7

The resolution is also showing up as 320x480 even though i'm running the Retina iPhone Simulator. The resolution should be 640x960, if i'm correct? Retina display is enabled also.

Comment: winsize is in points, not pixels, o 320x480 is correct even on retina

Comment: Thank you but that still doesn't fix my problem...

Comment: that problem sounds a lot like the common problem of cocos2d always launching the 1st scene in portait. Have a look around for the solution(s).